# Networking in virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

I have one guest running on Virtual Box on Ubuntu host and one guest running on virtual box on Ubuntu on another host. I want to communicate from one guest to anther guest. How can I do that in Virtual Box?

Comment: How exactly are you wanting to communicate with them? Have you bridged them both with your network adapter? if so you should be able to see them on your network. Thus being able to communicate.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Thanks for the reply! I tried bridging but cannot ping between the guests in different hosts. In one host i assigned an ip address to eth0 (10.10.10.8) and bridged the port to instance and assigned IP address to eth0 on instance (10.10.10.9). In another host I assigned assigned an ip address to eth0 (10.10.10.10) and bridged the port to instance and assigned IP address to eth0 on instance (10.10.10.11). Now i cannot ping two guests. i.e .11 to .9. i have disabled firewall and enabled ip forwarding in sysctl.conf. Am i missing anything. is this correct way to do?

Comment: @Hasha have a look over here and see if you have it setup like this. Have a look [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/711595/ping-between-guest-vms-in-virtualbox) let me know if this works for you.

Comment: And my bad missed a letter in your name.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Thanks for replying! I have configured exactly as mentioned in the figures with promiscuous turned on for all.  I'm able to ping the in between guests on a single host. The problem is i cannot ping guests on different hosts.

Comment: If the answer below did not help you i will set up a small test on my home lab when im off work.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin It is working now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Harsha consider marking the question resolved then, please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want feel of independent network between virtual machines, the best solution is VDE or UDP tunnels. In this case, VBox will encapsulate VM packets into UDP and send them over physical network, then decapsulate and inject into VM. VM will see completely independent network, and hosts will see UDP streams with VM traffic (unencrypted, so you will be able to analyze what is going there).

This is described as "generic networking" in manual https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes

and there are exact commands of how to set it up:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_udp_tunnel

2. Alternatively, you can use 802.1q VLANs. VirtualBox network filter works correctly with Linux networking capabilities like vlan subinterfaces, lacp bonds and so on (I've had thoroughly tested this).
   You create vlan subinterface on each host (use ubuntu or debian manual how to do this), and bridge your VMs with that subinterface. Make sure your switch forwards tagged packets. This option might be harder to set up, but it has some advantages. For example, your Ubuntu hosts will not see any VM traffic on their "default" base inteface, and Windows hosts are not able to see 802.1q tagged packets at all so only interference will be due to shared bandwidth.
3. If you don't need to feel completely independend network, just bridge your VMs with physical LAN and set up different IP network there. Simple, but for many cases this is sufficient.